# how can i collect this with javascript

Tags: jquery, ajax

i have the following markup

```
<form method="post" action="" id=form_1>
    <input type="hidden" name="night[]" value="1311976800"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="night[]" value="1312063200"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="night[]" value="1312149600"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="night[]" value="1312236000"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="night[]" value="1312322400"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="night[]" value="1312408800"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="night[]" value="1312495200"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="night[]" value="1312581600"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="night[]" value="1312668000"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="night[]" value="1312754400"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="room_id" id="1" value="1"/>
    <a href="rates_ajax.php?action=SubmitBook&lang=it&room_id=1&height=500&width=700" class="thickbox">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Book" class="allInputStuff inputSubmitRates"/></a>
</form>
```

and i need to collect the name="night[]"  how can this be done with Js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A followup on my comment (based on Thorsten's answer)

```
myarray = [];

$("input[name*='night[]']").each(function(){
    myarray.push($(this).val());
    //u can collect other attributes from $(this) inside here (like name?) 
});
```

Answer (score 2):

when looking for DOM elements by their names you can use

```
$('input[name="night[]"]')
```

Accessing the value is the same as in any other context

```
$('input[name="night[]"]').val()
```

or

```
$('input[name="night[]"]').each(function(){...})
```

Hope that's what you're lookin for

Comment: You can leave out some of your ". $('input[name=night[]]') selects the same collection as $('input[name="night[]"]')

Answer (score 2):

As comma-seperated list:

```
$('input[name="night[]"').map(function() { return $(this).attr('value'); }).get().join(',');
```

Comment: You have a typo at the end of `night[]`, should be `input[name="night[]"]`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can use jQuery, you can use the following line to search for a specific attribute name:

```
$('input[value*="1312668000"]')
```

...and from there you can use `.val()`

Comment: i need to collect them all into an array, just as i did with php

Comment: @tada, you can start from the answer of madC, just arrange it at you need

Comment: In that case, Thorsten's answer is sounds right. You can use that each() method (which will call the inline function for every element matched) to take each value and push it into an array.